# Fork join pool of 2-Dimensional Array slower than running in one thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use a fork join pool to sum my array.
But it somehow slower than running it in one thread. I can't understand why it happens.

one thread implementation

```
    private static void calc(int[][] arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    int row = arr.length;
    int column = arr[0].length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.print("sum: " + sum + "\n");
}
```

then I use nanotime to measure performance

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    calc(arr);
    long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("one thread: " + (stopTime - startTime) + "\n");
```

forkJoin case

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

class ForkJoin extends RecursiveAction {
  int maxCall;
  int[] data;
  int start, end;
  public static int sum = 0;
  
  ForkJoin(int[] nums, int s, int e, int t) {
    data = nums;
    start = s;
    end = e;
    maxCall = t;
  }

  protected void compute() {
    if ((end - start) < maxCall) {
      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
          sum += data[i];
      }
    } else {
      int middle = (start + end) / 2;
      invokeAll(new ForkJoin(data, start, middle, maxCall), new ForkJoin(data, middle, end, maxCall));
    }
  }

    
  public ForkJoin(int[][] nums) {
        int threads = 32;
        int maxCall = 10000;
        long beginT, endT;

        ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(threads);

        int row = nums.length;
        int column = nums[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            ForkJoin task = new ForkJoin(nums[i], 0, column, maxCall);
            fjp.invoke(task);
        }
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
  }
}
```

on arr[15][10] I got these numbers.
one thread: 402200
fork join: 3241900

Comment: 32 threads?? How many cores do you have? And setup time is a factor.  Threads aren't always faster.

Comment: pardon me 12 but the result is the same

Comment: Having multiple threads doesn't necessarily make things quicker. Btw there is a bug: `static int sum = 0;` means parallel run may compute different sum.

Comment: thank you, I will rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case since your tasks are so small the overhead of using threads is just not worth it.

If you want to use threads in this use-case make each task a larger chunk of work.

Answer (score 1):

1. **The overhead of spawning new threads is much larger than your task at hand.** Benefits of parallelism are more pronounced when the task has substantial amount of computation involved or has operations like I/O which take time.
2. Furthermore, **you should try to keep your number of threads according to the number of cores your CPU has**. Simply, spawning more threads won't help you since you are limited by your hardware resources, It will only increase the overhead for thread creation and switching between threads as well as the number of threads waiting in queue. Here is a resource explaining it in greater detail:
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80427